Figure Format Questions
May I know:
1/ how to move the description (blue) start with new line exactly under Abbildung? tried adding // but failed
2/ how to handle the spaces (red)?
3/ how to make the code (green) shown as role="status"?
( Latex original Code: \texttt{role="status"} )
Any of tips would be appreciated, especially question 3, searched & tried methods but failed.
Thanks a lot!
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} % Adjust the width as needed
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{basket-status-change}
  \captionsetup{font=small} 
  \caption{Produktdetailseite: Ankündigung der dynamischen Aktualisierungen (NVDA Sprachausgaben-Betrachter)}
  \label{fig:basket-status-change}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.05\textwidth} % Adjust the horizontal space between figures
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{basket-status-change-with-role_marked}
  \captionsetup{font=small} 
  \caption{Produktdetailseite: Quellcode zeigt die Verwendung von des Attribut/Wert-Paars \texttt{role="status"}}
\label{fig:basket-status-change-with-role_marked}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}



Welcome. // Please provide a code excerpt, which compiles, that produces your problem. Thank you

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

The output role = ßtatus" clearly means that you're using babel-german, so " is a shorthand character that, if followed by s produces the “scharfes es” ß.
In order to neutralize the effect you can input "{}status" or use
``status''

THe other problem is solved with labelsep=newline.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\captionsetup{labelsep=newline}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\captionsetup{font=small}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth} % Adjust the width as needed
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Produktdetailseite: Ankündigung der dynamischen 
    Aktualisierungen (NVDA Sprachausgaben-Betrachter)}
\label{fig:basket-status-change}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Produktdetailseite: Quellcode zeigt die Verwendung von 
des Attribut/Wert-Paars \texttt{role="{}status"}}
\label{fig:basket-status-change-with-role_marked}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}


Note the [t] option to minipage so, if the two images have the same height, they will be typeset side by side.
You probably need to review all \captionsetup instructions you have and remove format=hang.

Thank you for your kind, prompt and detailed help, role="{}status" problem was solved immediately :) Would you know if there is a quick way, that I don't have to recheck each figure? some captions are disappeared after using labelsep=newline. If it is not possible, that's ok, any way to only solve the spacing problems? they appear at captions as well as sentences near hyphen-used words in the main text, thanks for being so helpful, even to a stranger.

@user12595983 It's quite hard to debug without seeing code.
